# Remove Paragraph Tags

Tags: html, cakephp, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-2.0

In My code i want to print the value of Ck Editor but it shows  tags like ptag text ptag how can i remove the  ptags in my view file

```
echo "<td style='text-align:$sAlignment'>".$this->Html->link($arr_data['answer'], array('plugin' => 'user','controller' => 'user', 'action' => 'action',"id"=>$arr_data["id"],"slug"=>$arr_data['slug'],'admin' => true), array('class' => 'pass-reset-link'), null, null, false)."&nbsp;</td>";
```

Comment: *Just* `<p>` elements, or all HTML?

Comment: I dont want only <p> elements at the start and end of the text

Answer (score 1):

Finally I got it and this is the solution...

```
echo "<td style='text-align:$sAlignment'>".$this->Html->link(strip_tags($arr_data['answer']), array('plugin' => 'user','controller' => 'user', 'action' => 'action',"id"=>$arr_data["id"],"slug"=>$arr_data['slug'],'admin' => true), array('class' => 'pass-reset-link'), null, null, false)."&nbsp;</td>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the below line to the ckeditor.js configuration file:

> n.setRules('p',{indent:false,breakAfterOpen:false});

For more information go through the below links:

http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/Output_Formatting

http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Howto/Removing_Files